# COM Interop usage (converting from C++ to C#/.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I have a few COM libraries (TISCOPELib and MIPPARAMLib) that I have been using in C++ (unmanaged) and now I'm converting to C#.

This snippet of code works in C++:

```
TISCOPELib::IFilterBlockCasette *casette;
... inialization ...
int position = casette->Position;
... other stuff ...
```

In C#, I would have to do one of the following:

```
TISCOPELib.IFilterBlockCasette casette = microscope.FilterBlockCasette1; // Init stuff.
MIPPARAMLib.IMipParameter param = casette.Position;
int position = param.RawValue;
... other stuff ...
```

Or

```
TISCOPELib.IFilterBlockCasette casette = microscope.FilterBlockCasette1; // Init stuff.
int position = casette._Position;
... other stuff ...
```

If I did this:

```
TISCOPELib.IFilterBlockCasette casette = microscope.FilterBlockCasette1; // Init stuff.
int position = casette.Position;
... other stuff ...
```

I would get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
>
> Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'int'

The `System.__ComObject` in this case is supposed to be `IMipParameter` with `int` as the `RawValue` property.

So what is the best course of action here? Use a IMipParameter intermediate step, use _Position, or is there another solution? If I used the IMipParameter, is there a way I can get static type checking?

Comment: COM supports default properties, a property with DISPID 0.  Looks like RawValue is such a property.  C# doesn't like default properties beyond the indexer, RawValue doesn't qualify since the property getter doesn't take an argument.  You better spell it out.

Comment: The main issue I have with using RawValue is that it has a dynamic type, so I can't use the static type checking I get with the _Property.

Comment: I don't get the problem, you dislike typing an underscore or something?  You could edit the IL of the interop assembly but that's a bit gross.  The object model isn't very clear btw.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms247299%28office.11%29.aspx) The underscored properties are supposed to be for internal use only. EDIT: And they are kind of ugly.

Comment: That's a VB6 convention.  A language that doesn't have any trouble handling variants.  Nor does vb.net btw, maybe you'll like it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int position = (int)casette.Position.RawValue;
```

Comment: Yeah, that works too, but I still don't get the static type checking I'd get with _Position.